# Step by step recursion

Tags: c++

```
int f(int x)
{
  if (x < 1)
    return 0;
  else  
    return f(x - 3) + x;
}
```

Can some one explain how it calculates the final result for f(10)=22?
step by step please

Comment: Why don't you write it out on paper?

Comment: Using a debugger can also help.

Answer (score 2):

Working through this step by step is not difficult.

```
f(10)
f(10 - 3) + 10
(f(7 - 3) + 7) + 10
((f(4 - 3) + 4) + 7) + 10
(((f(1 - 3) + 1) + 4) + 7) + 10
(((0 + 1) + 4) + 7) + 10
((1 + 4) + 7) + 10
(5 + 7) + 10
12 + 10
22
```

Of course, this is just starting at a given number, and counting down by three, summing all positive numbers encountered. This doesn't require recursion.

```cpp
int f(int x) {
    int sum = 0;

    while (x > 0) {
        sum += x;
        x -= 3;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f(10) = f(7) + 10 = f(4) + 10 + 7 = f(1) + 10 + 7 + 4 = f(-2) + 10 + 7 + 4 + 1 = 0 + 10 + 7 + 4 + 1
```